# How do you store an Enum value into a HashMap?

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

I am a java noob, so bear with me.

I am trying to store a PlayerState (an Enum) with a player name in a hash map.  I want to add players to the hashmap when a listener is triggered by them joining the server.  Thus I am using a method that I can access from that class.  My issue is that my IDE is showing me that there is an error and that it wants to "cast" my code.  I am so lost on how I am supposed to do this so if you know anything. Please help.

Here is my code.

```
public class PlayerHandler {

    private static HashMap<Player, PlayerState> playerMap = new HashMap<>();

    public PlayerHandler() {

    }

    public void addPlayer(Player player, PlayerState state) {
        playerMap.add(player, PlayerState.values());
    }

    public static PlayerState getPlayer(Player player) {
        return playerMap.get(player);
    }

}
```

Here is the Enum I made.

```
public enum PlayerState {

    IN_LOBBY(true), IN_GAME(false), DEAD(false);

    private boolean canPlay;

    private static PlayerState currentState;

        PlayerState(boolean canPlay) {
            this.canPlay = canPlay;
        }

        public boolean canPlay() {
            return canPlay();
        }

        public static void setState(PlayerState state) {
            currentState = state;
        }

        public static boolean isState(PlayerState state) {
            return PlayerState.currentState == state;
        }

        public static PlayerState getState() {
            return currentState;
        }

}
```

[image: My Error]

Comment: If you're seeing an error, post the full error message, not your interpretation of it. Show the line that is causing it. Don't make us guess please. Also consider getting all static declarations out of that code.

Comment: How about an EnumMap https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html

Comment: @frozen: I don't think that yours is a good recommendation. That's for when the key is an enum, which is not the case here. Here the value is an enum. In fact, I'm sure that your advise will only serve to confuse a newbie. Please delete.

Comment: playerMap.add(player, state);

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added A photo of the error.  Hope that helps you out.

Comment: @Càphêđen I tried that but it did not work.... It was the same error.

Comment: There are many things wrong in your PlayerState enum code snippet you just posted. That's not how enums are meant to be used. Most of that code should be in your Player or PlayerHandler class not your PlayerState enum. There are other things wrong with it too that are too long for me to explain in a comment.

Comment: You appear to be trying to learn to code by making random guesses. If you want to save yourself from terrible frustration,  don't do this. Read the tutorials and the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to passing `state` as the PlayerState instead of `PlayerState.values()`. Also, because playerMap is a HashMap you be using the put method instead of the add method so instead of `playerMap.add(player, PlayerState.values());` it should be `playerMap.put(player, state);`

If you have further questions about HashMaps you should take a look at the [HashMap documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: Same error. :\ Any other ideas?

Comment: Also change add() to put().

Comment: Okay, that seemed to work.  But can you explain why?  Is `.put()` and `.add()` the same?

Comment: `.add()` is for Lists and `.put()` is for Maps. Just search `hashmap java` to find the documentation for HashMaps so you know which methods are available.

Comment: Ah thank you very much